# Computer failing to boot using a graphic card with the driver installed

Tags: windows-7, drivers, motherboard

I'm having some troubles with my computer. Yesterday I had a bluescreen about some graphic driver dll and couldn't boot the computer back. I swapped my graphic card for a backup and could boot the computer again. This morning things fell apart pretty quickly, the two graphic card weren't working anymore and the screen went black right after the "Starting Windows" animation. I tried to format but the problem persisted with the two GPUs, I just tried a backup PSU thinking it may be the problem but it still happen. Now I can use windows if I have no graphics driver (So windows use the generics ones) or if I use the onboard intel graphics but as soon as I plug a GPU back, I get blackscreens right after the boot animation.

I also tried plugging the GPUs in the second PCI Express slot without any effect. I'm starting to think it may be a motherboard problem but I would prefer to be sure before starting a RMA. Is there any tests I could do to narrow my problem down?

Informations about the computer :
Windows 7 64 bits
i7 3770 with Asus P8Z77 motherboard
First GPU GTX 470 and the backup one is a GTS 250
First PSU was 910Watts and the backup one was a 650Watts

Edit : Forgot to mention I did try an older driver in cas the latest was causing problems. No change

Comment: sounds like a motherboard problem to me. Are you absolutely sure both Graphics cards work 100%? Also make sure the graphics cards are getting the power they need, IF they need power.

Comment: Well, I'm not 100% but the backup card was working last time I used it. About the power, I thought about it too, that's why I tried a second PSU since the problem seems to appear right when the cards start consuming power (When the monitors go full resolution at boot). But the backup psu here I'm convinced is working since it was running in a second machine before I took it.

Comment: If possible, put your GPUs in another computer and run some tests there. If they work fine it is almost certainly a motherboard issue.  And triple check your drivers.

Comment: I do not remember exactally but it is possible to have registry setting things that can cause your symptoms. So while it first looks like a power or MB problem, I dont trust software that much :-)  . If you reconfirm that the existance OF the video card does not fail, as long as the drivers are not installed?  It is possible that the guru3d driver cleaner thing can clear out an issue. It is to complex for me but there are registry settings that persist based on slot and ID, that might get in the way of re-starting this cleanly. (meaning I wouldnt give up hope until a re-install didnt fix it)

Comment: Well since I formatted I doubt any registry setting cause the problem. But yeah the fact that the problem only start to occur when drivers are installed... I will look at the tool you said and inform you of the results